# How to eliminate this loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I found my following code runs too slow, so I wonder anyone can help me eliminate the loop and make my code run faster. Here a and b are two lists of integers from 0 to 4, majority of those elements are 0.

```
sim_cal<-function(a,b){
  intScore <- 0 

  for (i in 1:length(a)){
    if (a[i]>0 && b[i]>0){
      intScore <- intScore + min(a[i],b[i])
    } 
  }
  return(intScore)
}
```

Comment: Are the values always nonnegative?

Comment: Yes, both Matthew and Blue gave excellent solutions, thanks

Comment: I did the testing since the elements could be 0, I only want to count when both are positive. I do appreciate your concise and beautiful answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all values are nonnegative, there is no reason to test that both are greater than zero, as the min of zero and any positive number is zero.  Thus, for any position where `a` or `b` is zero, nothing is added to the sum if you eliminate the test.

That leaves the following as an equivalent, simpler, solution:

```
sim_cal <- function(a,b) {
    sum(pmin(a,b))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sim_cal <- function(a,b) {
  sum(pmin(a,b)[a > 0 & b > 0])
}
```

Comment: `which` is not needed here (and only increases runtime) as logical indexing works fine.

Comment: Agreed: `which` is only needed if you want to discard `NA` inputs. I run into those cases enough that I usually wrap my subsetting vectors with `which`.